# Eclipse and CDT, sometimes build does not generate a new binary

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-cdt

The system is Linux. I have a C++ prjoject opened with eclipse. In another window I have a terminal in the folder where the binary is created. Normally I edit the project, I build it and i execute the binary from the terminal and it works. However sometimes it seems that the build doesn't update the binary. Anyone knows how to fix this behavior?

Note: I don't want to do a Clean manually all the times because isn't comfortable, expecially because I my touchpad's right click that doesn't work very well under Linux. However it would be ok if the clean was done automatically.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Do you have the save automatically before build setting set?
If you do not save your project before the build eclipse will not create a new binary.